# How to call a UDF with a parameter which is known only at "execution time"?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to join a table with another table, which is provided by a UDF.
Check out this self-explained piece of sql code:

```
SELECT table1.column1 FROM Table1 table1 
INNER JOIN UDF1(table1.column2) as UDF1 ON XXX(condition doesn´t matter)
WHERE table1.id=100
```

The problem is: table1.column2 can´t be resolved.

I can´t believe there is no way to get this done, but i can´t find how to do it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use a column from a table as a parameter to a UDF you need to use cross apply (or outer apply).

Test this. It might do what you want.

```
SELECT table1.column1 
FROM Table1 table1 
  CROSS APPLY UDF1(table1.column2) as UDF1
WHERE table1.id=100
```